# Stub authentication server used by ember-simple-auth during development

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I'm using [ember-simple-auth](http://ember-simple-auth.com/) in my emberjs app to authenticate via oauth2-password-grant with my own (currently unimplemented) service.

I'd like to continue developing the front-end before creating the authentication service.

Can the authentication service be stubbed so login/logout features can be used? I'm aware that I mock it with http-mock during tests, but I would also like to work on the front-end design and view it in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP mocks also run during development. You can also use [Pretender](https://github.com/pretenderjs/pretender) or [Mirage](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/) (a library built on top of Pretender) to clientside mocks.

In Mirage your route may look something like this:

```
// app/mirage/config.js
this.post('/users/sign_in', (db, request) => {
  return {
    user_email: "some.user@gmail.com",
    user_id: 1,
    user_token: "LcsBEYP2yjTcc-G7drto"
  };
});
```

depending on the shape of your backend response.

Comment: Mirage is really useful. Perfect for the job, thanks.